# How do I manually set the system time in VirtualBox?

Tags: virtualbox, time

I am trying to manually set the computer's time in VirtualBox but it always resets itself to what it was before I changed it. How can I disable ntp and tell the system what time I want it to be?

Comment: Can you give some more details about your problem? Whattime do you want it to be and what time sets your computer?

Comment: I want to set an arbitrary wrong time on my computer.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

I have found a solution. Read the following material: [link](http://www.forbesconrad.com/blog/virtualbox-linux-guest-incorrect-time-on-windows-host-solution)

Basically if you have Windows host and Ubuntu guest, do the following:

1. Find a name of your VM (Virtual Machine) - run VB (VirtualBox), select your VM, open settings, in 'General' tab check the name, e.g. in my case `Ubuntu 12.04 32bit`
2. In Windows, start a command line interpreter, go to `C:\Program Files\Oracle` folder and click `VirtualBox` to select, then holding left shift key, do a mouse right-button click and select "Open command window here" menu, the interpreter has to be running now
3. Paste the following command (change the VM name to your name!):

   `VBoxManage setextradata "Ubuntu 12.04 32bit"
   "VBoxInternal/Devices/VMMDev/0/Config/GetHostTimeDisabled" 1`
4. Finally, start your Ubuntu guest and set the time and date manually.

**Undo**

If required, to get the guest to sync time with the host again, repeat the above steps but change the final `1` to `0`.

Comment: this should definitely be the accepted answer! i didn't want to disable guest additions as i have a shared folder mounted in my ubuntu server 14 guest

Comment: Unfortunately, it does not "freeze" the time on the guest system. In some scenarios though you want to completely freeze all time (like for doing reproducible builds).

Comment: this just saved me a lot of time

Comment: If your host OS is Ubuntu, the command is: vboxmanage setextradata "your_VM_name_here" "VBoxInternal/Devices/VMMDev/0/Config/GetHostTimeDisabled" 1

Comment: See this question, it worked when I tried it:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/45724822/18149

The `vboxadd-service` needed an extra argument on the guest, mainly `--disable-timesync`

Answer (score 23):

As mentioned in another answer, if you are running Ubuntu as a Guest under VirtualBox then you should be aware that the system time is automatically kept in sync by the *Guest Additions* (i.e., not through an option in the motherboard settings).

Your solution in that case is to disable the Guest Additions, which can be achieved by executing

```
sudo service vboxadd-service stop
```

or

```
sudo /etc/init.d/vboxadd-service stop
```

You can then set the time as desired (from command line using `date --set` or using the system settings applet)

The VirtualBox service will be restarted at next reboot, or you can do it manually.

Comment: Off topic, but disabling/uninstalling Guest Additions allows you to set the system clock on Windows guest OSes as well

Comment: In my version of Ubuntu the command was `sudo service virtualbox-guest-utils stop`. I guess the package was renamed?

Comment: @Crashthatch your solution is the only one which works. thanks.

Answer (score 12):

The only way is to set the time in the Virtualbox motherboard using the command line:

```
VBoxManage modifyvm <name> --biossystemtimeoffset <msec>
```

For example, to set back the date 1 year:

```
VBoxManage modifyvm <name> --biossystemtimeoffset -31536000000
```

Answer (score 5):

Well, if you want to set arbitrary dates, first you should disable or deinstall ntp.

- To disable it, open a terminal and run `sudo update-rc.d -f ntp remove`
- To deinstall it, use your favorite software management software

After that you can use the `date`-command to set your system time:

```
date -s "17 April 2011 12:34:56"
date --set="17 April 2011 12:34:56"
```

Both commands are equivalent. To only set the time you can use:

```
date +%T -s "12:34:56"
```

The [`date`-manpage](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?date) has some more format controls. You can use them all to change the date

Comment: Ok, I've done that but sudo date -s only holds the date for a few seconds before reverting. By that, I mean, running date again shows the time I set working normally but the time indicator in the panel does not, and when I run date again, the time has switched to match the panel clock.....And trying to change the indicator-datetime clock doesn't work either. I think I'm going to have to open a bug.

Comment: Are you sure that deinstalled/disabled ntp? Do you some other automatic time management software (i.e. chrony) installed?

Comment: It's a new Natty install in VirtualBox and I purged anything ntp and did not install any other time management software.

Comment: Virtualbox „transfers“ the time from your host to the client. You'll have to change some options here. Maybe http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch03.html#settings-motherboard is helpful.

Answer (score 3):

Click on the time & date section of the panel, then the Calendar will appear and underneath that the Time & Date Settings is there so click that.

Click on the Padlock icon and enter your password, then choose Set The Time to manually.

Comment: I'm going to go ahead and mark this as the best answer for most users. My specific problem was with VirtualBox.

Answer (score 1):

In the Software Center look up ntpdate and remove it, or in terminal: sudo apt-get remove ntpdate

(You may have to reboot to fully disable ntp)

Then set your date.

Comment: Ok, I purged ntpdate and rebooted but I'm still unable to set the system clock and have it stick.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the ".ps1" (Windows PowerShell script) example given in

https://superuser.com/questions/539880/using-virtual-box-is-it-possible-to-set-your-virtual-machine-time-to-be-differen

I've written a regular ".bat" script file to change the clock time at which the VirtualBox's virtual machine starts.

The desired start time is set at variable "TEMPO_START_TIMESTAMP" in epoch format. You can get your desired start time epoh equivalent at "http://www.timestampconvert.com/".

The name of the VirtualBox's virtual machine to be started is needed in variable "NOME" (same nomenchature used in the ".ps1" script above).

```
echo off
echo %time%

set NOME="Windows_7_x64"

set TEMPO_CS_2_MS=0
set TEMPO_S_2_MS=000

rem # Starts the VM always on the date 07/11/2014 - 11h58
rem http://www.timestampconvert.com/

set   TEMPO_START_TIMESTAMP=1415361480

for /f "delims=" %%x in ('cscript /nologo toEpoch.vbs') do set epoch=%%x
rem %epoch%

set TEMPO_CURRENT_TIMESTAMP=%epoch%
rem set TEMPO_CURRENT_TIMESTAMP=1544518714

set /A TEMPO_TEMP=(%TEMPO_START_TIMESTAMP%-%TEMPO_CURRENT_TIMESTAMP%)

call set TEMPO=%TEMPO_TEMP%%TEMPO_S_2_MS%
rem %TEMPO_TEMP%
rem %TEMPO%

c:\Progra~1\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxManage setextradata %NOME% "VBoxInternal/Devices/VMMDev/0/Config/GetHostTimeDisabled" 1
c:\Progra~1\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxManage modifyvm %NOME% --biossystemtimeoffset %TEMPO%
c:\Progra~1\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxManage startvm %NOME%
```

You'll also need the current time in epoh format, for this use the following script (save as "toEpoch.vbs", this visual basic script is called from the ".bat" script above):

```
WScript.Echo DateDiff("s", "01/01/1970 00:00:00", Now())
```

To run the virtual machine, simply execute the ".bat" script file above. No need to open the "Oracle VM VirtualBox Administration" interface.

I hope this helps.

Regards